# How to password protect grub menu entry?

Tags: 12.04, grub2

Is there a way I can password protect grub menu entry- e.g. if I dual boot with Windows 7 can I set it so that a password is needed to boot into Win 7?

Secondly I would also like to protect grub menu entries being changed if possible.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a Wiki page on Ubuntu covering all type of password related topics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords).

Basically, edit your configuration

```
gksu gedit /etc/grub.d/00_header /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
```

Add this at the bottom of `00_header`:

```
cat << EOF
set superusers="user1" 
password user1 password1
EOF
```

That way the edits will be password protected, with that user and password.

Now, let's protect the Windows entry. Open `30_os-prober` and find this line:

```
menuentry '$(echo "${LONGNAME} $onstr" | grub_quote)' --class windows --class os \
```

On that line, add `--users`, so it ends like this:

```
menuentry '$(echo "${LONGNAME} $onstr" | grub_quote)' --class windows --class os --users \
```

Be careful on not removing the ending slash `\`.

Save and close, and then run this on a terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

You can also encrypt your password with `grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2`. Please take a look at the wiki for more details.

Comment: I have the line `menuentry "${LONGNAME} (on ${DEVICE})" --class windows --class os {` in that file, is this the same? I can't see any other mention of windows in the `30_os-prober` file.

Comment: Yes, I'm on 12.10, so that's the reason of the difference.