# Windows is not in grub menu after trying to put password on

Tags: grub2, windows

so I put a password on my menu entries followed this [How to password protect grub menu entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248196/how-to-password-protect-grub-menu-entry) guide exactly and now I don't see Windows 7 in grub on a reboot the ubuntu installation is password protected though I went to try and change the 330_os-prober line back and the --users isn't there im assuming it has something to do with the config file that was generated?

SO i think something happened to the menu entry but anyway does anyone know if you can boot windows at grub command prompt? I dont want to get rid of either ubuntu but restore the mbr with a disc or windows

UPDATE: so I went in removed --users from the line in 30_os-probe ran sudo update-grub and windows 7 appeared and im prompted to user and password to boot ubuntu or windows 7 im very confused I thought adding&removing the --users part in 30_os-probe was the part that makes a user&password requirement

Comment: one more thing when I run sudo update-grub I get this

Comment: Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done